# Checkout or clone SubDirectory in Git

Tags: git

We have recently migrated to Git. We have very big repository and it has many modules that can be build independently. Our CI server currently has different jobs setup i.e. each job for each project that can build independently. However it takes a lot of time to clone, since it clones the whole repo. Is there anyway that i can checkout a subtree from the complete repo.

I checked the sparse feature but it seems that it will still clone the whole repo but files wont be visible or so it seems but it wont have any performance benefit. We are planning to cut the big repo into multiple repos but it will take sometime and approvals.

Until that is there way to do a sub tree clone or checkout which gives us performance benefit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to clone a git repository's sub-directory only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-git-repositorys-sub-directory-only)

Comment: Why does it need to clone all the time? Shouldn't it be able to `pull` subsequent builds? That should at least solve the performance problem (if not the disk space usage).